# auto-save (and auto-delete) screen recorder video?

Tags: video, automation, video-recording

I set up my old phone as a security camera and downloaded *SimpleScreenRecorder* to record it. However I would like to find a program that would allow me to auto save say every hour and auto delete videos after several days.

I can manually delete, so I would be content with a way to auto save.

Comment: Is it an Ubuntu Phone? Or how is this related to Ubuntu? Is your phone connected to a Ubuntu PC?

Comment: andriod phone but thats beside the point i have it streaming video to a pc and i need to record my screen as it plays on the screen
i am currently doing so with simple screen recorder but i would like to find a way to auto save the videos

Comment: please add the folder, where your files are stored on your Computer

Comment: thanks
I have rudimentary skills with scripting, 
but I will try to stumble though this.
the folder I have them saved to at the moment is videos however I was planning on changing this later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any extra software. Linux is shipped with such functionality already in the form of [`cron`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/man5/crontab.5.html):

Just create a script `/etc/cron.hourly/archive_screenrecorder_files`:

```
#!/bin/sh
DATE=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M")
ARCHIVE=/path/to/archive/$DATE
mkdir -p $ARCHIVE
mv /path/to/recordings/* $ARCHIVE/
```

and another file `/etc/cron.daily/delete_screenrecorder_files` that will be executed once a day (the hour and minute is defined in `/etc/crontab`)